# One of multiple monitors has wrong orientation

Tags: display, multiple-monitors

I am using win 7 with dual monitors
Brand new Dell computer
I hit a key or keys accidentally and now my left monitor is correctly orientated but my left monitor is upside down. I am sure the fix is something simple..I've tried ctl-alt-r or l arrow and that changes both but does not get them both orientated correctly.  HELP

Answer (score 3):

First of all try Pressing these key combinations. `CTRL+ALT+↓ (Down Arrow)`

If that works, you're set!

If not, the easiest way to do this is through the Windows built-in Screen Resolution Control Panel Window. Otherwise the graphics card control panel can be used as well. By the hotkey (CTRL+ALT+Arrow), I can tell that you either have Intel or NVIDIA graphics card and its corresponding software. All these methods are explained in detail below.

Right click your desktop to determine which graphics card you have.

If you have an Intel graphics card, there will be a context menu displaying **Graphics Properties**. 
If you have a NVIDIA grpahics card, there will be a context menu displaying **NVIDIA Control Panel**.
If you have an AMD grpahics card, there will be a context menu displaying **AMD Catalyst Control Center**.

### Windows Built-In Feature

[image]

1. Right click desktop and Select Screen resolution.
2. Select your monitor and change it to Landscape (or whichever orientation you prefer).

### Intel Graphics Card

[Follow this Guide on Intel's Website.](http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/cs-016829.htm)

### NVIDIA Graphics Card

[image]

1. Right click desktop and select the NVIDIA Control Panel option.
2. Display > Rotate Display
3. Select your monitor and change it to Landscape (or whichever orientation you prefer).

### AMD Graphics Card

[image]

1. Right click desktop and select the AMD Catalyst Control Center option.
2. Common Display Tasks > Rotate Desktop
3. Select your monitor and change it to Landscape (or whichever orientation you prefer).

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

1. Right-click Desktop
2. Click "Screen Resolution"
3. Select the right monitor
4. Under 'Orientation' select 'Landscape'. If it is already on 'Landscape' then select 'Landscape (inverted)'
5. Click "apply"

See if that works for you.